# Different versions of app for different devices

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, screen-size

I am developing an iOS app for 4-inch screen. That means my app looks terrible on 3.5-inch screen because of images. If I published it in App Store, would it be possible to download this application for 3.5-inch iphone users? If I want to make a version of my app for 3.5-inch screens, should I just make two different projects?

Comment: Have you heard of auto layout?

Comment: or struts / springs, or using -568h@2x in the file name for only 4 inch phones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't stop people with a 3.5'' device downloading, however:

You can support both 4'' and 3.5'' devices with the same application.

You need to programmatically check which device you're currently running on and then layout your UI appropriately.

As a simple example, you can check if you're on a 4'' device (iPhone 5, 5C, 5s) with the below code snippet:

```
#define isFourInch  ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568)?TRUE:FALSE


 if (isFourInch)
 {
       //4'' screen detected
 }
 else
 {

       //3.5'' screen detected
 }
```

Because iOS 7 supports devices with 3.5" screens, you can't use the only-support-iOS-x technique.

Also, there isn't a setting in Xcode or a key for UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities which allows you to make the app 4-inch only.

Comment: In all honesty I would use `#define IS_WIDESCREEN ( fabs( ( double )[ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.height - ( double )568 ) < DBL_EPSILON )` this sort of detection over checking just the bounds, but that is personal preference.

Comment: Agree it's more elegant, updated answer.

Comment: Your answer wasn't wrong I was just noting an alternative based on personal preference but +1 for the update.

Comment: Be careful using this with iPhone 6 because the else will catch iPhone 4 and iPhone 6, 6 Plus.